# What is the safest way to click on an element in Playwright?

Tags: python, automation, playwright

I need to click on an object using **Playwright for Python**! Sometimes the element's CSS changes, or it doesn't have an ID. I usually use
`page.click(XPATH)`, But I know there are many other ways like:

```
1 - page.get_by_text("Get Started").click()
2 - page.get_by_role("button", name="Submit").click()
3 - page.get_by_selector("#login-button").click()
4 - page.get_by_selector("//div[@class='user-agent']").click()
5 - locator = page.locator(".user-agent")
    locator.click()
```

Which has the highest probability of success?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playwright has written som good advices: https://playwright.dev/docs/best-practices#best-practices (they are in the node.js docs, but the message is the same with Python). Personally, I agree with them: Write test based on whats visible to the user (get_by_text, get_by_role), tests depending on css/xpath etc. is more prone to flakiness.

Answer (score 0):

```
2 - page.get_by_role("button", name="Submit").click()
```

If Id is not available, I would tend to favor  option 2 as its:

1. **Unique** : Usually there is only one submit button on a page.
2. **combination**: Two properties are less likely to change at the same time.
3. **User facing property**: As we are relying on user facing properties it's more safe as they less likely to change compared to internal properties like 'class' which may change for various reasons.

> I think the most desirable quality in a locator is - `rigid and flexible at the same time`, which second option has it.